# How can I prevent scope variable from changing whenever the model value changes in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my controller function in typescript:

```
let temp = null;

temp = _.find(this.scope.model.maintenanceArray, 
         function(_data,_key) {
           return _data.iD === currentId;
}
this.scope.originalData = temp;
this.scope.maintenanceData = temp;
```

And in the view,

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="dateFrom"         
placeholder="{{dateDefault}}"
ng-model="maintenanceData.from" required />
```

Basically I used maintenanceData for ngModel and want to keep originalData as it is. But the problem is that originalData is changed every time the model changes. How can I prevent originalData from updating?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because the variable `temp` is passed by reference to both `originalData` and `maintenanceData`, so both of those variables reference the same object. To avoid this you can create a copy of the `temp` object for one of the two variables. Like this:

```
this.scope.originalData = angular.copy(temp);
this.scope.maintenanceData = temp;
```

There are several other ways to copy objects out there, so this is just one example.